# CN name shows different when connected over libssl vs openssl

Tags: openssl, libssl

CN name show *azureedge.net while connecting over libssl and shows actual hostname while connect over openssl.

Tried libressl in mac and libssl inside code to perform sslconnectfor a host
While openssl returned CN as actual domain, others returned azureedge.net

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the commandline program `openssl s_client`; if so in real OpenSSL 1.1.1 up (I don't speak for LibreSSL) that sends [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) which many servers today (and for about a decade) use to select the correct server certificate. BTW so do `curl` and `wget` for much longer, Java in most cases, and nodejs and python in some. In native code call [`SSL_set_tlsext_host_name`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/SSL_set_tlsext_host_name.html) before the handshake.

Comment: In addition to @dave_thompson_085 's comment, you can also try `openssl s_client -noservername -connect ...` to *disable* sending the server name via SNI.  That will allow you to compare the returned data with what you're getting programmatically.